# Stepper input and data issues in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

We are using the stepper in flutter and we are seeing weird data issues in the example we are trying to implement.  When you type into the Firstname textbox it doesnt type it in right away, you have to do it more than once and the firstname shows in the Last name text area too. Very strange behavior, Im not sure when we found this example maybe its not a good one :)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:validators/validators.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:lightbridge_mobile/models/user_step1_model .dart';
import 'package:lightbridge_mobile/screens/member/profile/step2.dart';
import 'package:lightbridge_mobile/models/user.dart';



class ProfileStep1 extends StatefulWidget {
  final User user;

  const ProfileStep1({Key key, this.user}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
return new MyAppScreenMode(user: user);
 }
}

class MyData {
  String firstname = '';
  String lastname = '';
  String phone = '';
  String email = '';

  }

class MyAppScreenMode extends State<ProfileStep1> {
  final User user;

  MyAppScreenMode({@required this.user});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new MaterialApp(
    theme: new ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey
    ),
    home: new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(1,89,99, 1.0),
        title:  Container(child: Row(children: <Widget>[
          Icon(
                     FontAwesomeIcons.userPlus,
                     size: 25.0,
                     color: Colors.white,

             ),
           new Text('   Create Account : Step 1 of 5'),
        ],
        ),
        ),

        ),

         body: Container(
        child: StepperBody(user: user),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: new LinearGradient(
            colors: [Color.fromRGBO(1,89,99, 1.0),Color.fromRGBO(1,89,99, 1.0),],
            begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            end: Alignment.topRight
        )
    ),
    )
    )
    );
 }
}

    class StepperBody extends StatefulWidget {
     final User user;
     const StepperBody({Key key,@required this.user}) : super(key: key);
     @override
    _StepperBodyState createState() => new _StepperBodyState();
 }

 class _StepperBodyState extends State<StepperBody> {
 int currStep = 0;
 static var _focusNode = new FocusNode();
  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  static MyData data = new MyData();



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
      print('Has focus: $_focusNode.hasFocus');
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
   _focusNode.dispose();
   super.dispose();
  }

   List<Step> steps = [
    new Step(
       title: const Text('First Name', style: TextStyle( color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 19.0 )),

       isActive: true,

         state: StepState.indexed,
       content: new TextFormField(
         focusNode: _focusNode,
       keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      autocorrect: false,
      onSaved: (String fnvalue) {
        data.firstname = fnvalue;
      },
      maxLines: 1,
      validator: (fnvalue) {
        if (fnvalue.isEmpty || fnvalue.length < 1) {
          return 'Please enter first name';
        }
      },
      decoration: new InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Enter your first name',
          icon: const Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.white),
          labelStyle:
              new TextStyle(decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.solid,color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0))
              ),
       ),

    new Step(
    title: const Text('Last Name', style: TextStyle( color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 19.0 )),   
    isActive: false,
    state: StepState.indexed,
    content: new TextFormField(
      focusNode: _focusNode,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      autocorrect: false,
      onSaved: (String lnvalue) {
        data.lastname = lnvalue;
      },
      maxLines: 1,
      validator: (lnvalue) {
        if (lnvalue.isEmpty || lnvalue.length < 1) {
          return 'Please enter last name';
        }
      },
      decoration: new InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Enter your last name',
          icon: const Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.white),
          labelStyle:
              new TextStyle(decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.solid)),
    )),
new Step(
    title: const Text('Phone',style: TextStyle( color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 19.0 )),
    //subtitle: const Text('Subtitle'),
    isActive: false,
    //state: StepState.editing,
    state: StepState.indexed,
    content: new TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
      autocorrect: false,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 10) {
          return 'Please enter valid number';
        }
      },
      onSaved: (String value) {
        data.phone = value;
      },
      maxLines: 1,
      decoration: new InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Enter your number',
          icon: const Icon(Icons.phone, color: Colors.white),
          labelStyle:
              new TextStyle(decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.solid, color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0)),
    )),
new Step(
    title: const Text('Email', style: TextStyle( color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 19.0 )),
    // subtitle: const Text('Subtitle'),
    isActive: false,
    state: StepState.indexed,
    // state: StepState.disabled,
    content: new TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      autocorrect: false,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
          return 'Please enter valid email';
        }
      },
      onSaved: (String value) {
        data.email = value;
      },
      maxLines: 1,
      decoration: new InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Enter your email',
          hintText: 'Enter a email address',
          icon: const Icon(Icons.email, color: Colors.white),
          labelStyle:
              new TextStyle(decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.solid, color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0))),
    ),

  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void showSnackBarMessage(String message,
       [MaterialColor color = Colors.red]) {
      Scaffold
        .of(context)
        .showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: new Text(message)));
   }

    void _submitDetails() {
     final FormState formState = _formKey.currentState;

     if (!formState.validate()) {
       showSnackBarMessage('Please enter correct data');
     } else {
    formState.save();
    // HERE
    insertUserStep1(data.firstname, data.lastname, data.email, data.phone);

  }
}

return new Container(
    child: new Form(
  key: _formKey,
  child: new ListView(children: <Widget>[
    new Stepper(
      steps: steps,
      type: StepperType.vertical,
      currentStep: this.currStep,
      onStepContinue: () {
        setState(() {
          if (currStep < steps.length - 1) {
            currStep = currStep + 1;
          } else {
            currStep = 0;
          }
          // else {
          // Scaffold
          //     .of(context)
          //     .showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: new Text('$currStep')));

          // if (currStep == 1) {
          //   print('First Step');
          //   print('object' + FocusScope.of(context).toStringDeep());
          // }

          // }
        });
      },
      onStepCancel: () {
        setState(() {
          if (currStep > 0) {
            currStep = currStep - 1;
          } else {
            currStep = 0;
          }
        });
      },
      onStepTapped: (step) {
        setState(() {
          currStep = step;
        });
      },
    ),

      Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
       child: OutlineButton(
             child: Text('Tap to Continue'), textColor: Colors.white,
          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
            onPressed: _submitDetails,

            )
            //  Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new ProfileStep1()));
        ),
   ] ),







));
```

}

```
  Future<void> insertUserStep1(String firstname, String lastname, String email, String cell ) async 
   {
      final response =
     await http.post('http://url/api/UserStep1',
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json", 
             'Accept': 'application/json',},
  body: json.encode({'firstname' : firstname,'lastname' : lastname ,  'email' : email, 'cell': cell}));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON
UserStep1Model _user;
    _user = UserStep1Model.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new ProfileStep2(userID: _user.userId)));

 } else {
// If that call was not successful, throw an error.
throw Exception('Failed to load user');
   }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can let first name `TextFormField` and last name `TextFormField` use different `focusNode` 
code snippet

```
content: new TextFormField(
          focusNode: _focusNode,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,

content: new TextFormField(
          focusNode: _focusNodeLastName,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
```

working demo

[image]
full test code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: ProfileStep1(user: User()),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ProfileStep1 extends StatefulWidget {
  final User user;

  const ProfileStep1({Key key, this.user}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new MyAppScreenMode(user: user);
  }
}

class User {}

class MyData {
  String firstname = '';
  String lastname = '';
  String phone = '';
  String email = '';
}

class MyAppScreenMode extends State<ProfileStep1> {
  final User user;

  MyAppScreenMode({@required this.user});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        theme: new ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey),
        home: new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
              backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(1, 89, 99, 1.0),
              title: Container(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.userPlus,
                      size: 25.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    new Text('   Create Account : Step 1 of 5'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            body: Container(
              child: StepperBody(user: user),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: new LinearGradient(colors: [
                Color.fromRGBO(1, 89, 99, 1.0),
                Color.fromRGBO(1, 89, 99, 1.0),
              ], begin: Alignment.bottomLeft, end: Alignment.topRight)),
            )));
  }
}

class StepperBody extends StatefulWidget {
  final User user;
  const StepperBody({Key key, @required this.user}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _StepperBodyState createState() => new _StepperBodyState();
}

class _StepperBodyState extends State<StepperBody> {
  int currStep = 0;
  static var _focusNode = new FocusNode();
  static var _focusNodeLastName = new FocusNode();
  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  static MyData data = new MyData();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
      print('Has focus: $_focusNode.hasFocus');
    });

    _focusNodeLastName.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
      print('Has focus: $_focusNode.hasFocus');
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusNode.dispose();
    _focusNodeLastName.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  List<Step> steps = [
    new Step(
      title: const Text('First Name',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 19.0)),
      isActive: true,
      state: StepState.indexed,
      content: new TextFormField(
          focusNode: _focusNode,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          autocorrect: false,
          onSaved: (String fnvalue) {
            data.firstname = fnvalue;
          },
          maxLines: 1,
          validator: (fnvalue) {
            if (fnvalue.isEmpty || fnvalue.length < 1) {
              return 'Please enter first name';
            }
          },
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Enter your first name',
              icon: const Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.white),
              labelStyle: new TextStyle(
                  decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.solid,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 16.0))),
    ),
    new Step(
        title: const Text('Last Name',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 19.0)),
        isActive: false,
        state: StepState.indexed,
        content: new TextFormField(
          focusNode: _focusNodeLastName,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          autocorrect: false,
          onSaved: (String lnvalue) {
            data.lastname = lnvalue;
          },
          maxLines: 1,
          validator: (lnvalue) {
            if (lnvalue.isEmpty || lnvalue.length < 1) {
              return 'Please enter last name';
            }
          },
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Enter your last name',
              icon: const Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.white),
              labelStyle:
                  new TextStyle(decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.solid)),
        )),
    new Step(
        title: const Text('Phone',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 19.0)),
        //subtitle: const Text('Subtitle'),
        isActive: false,
        //state: StepState.editing,
        state: StepState.indexed,
        content: new TextFormField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
          autocorrect: false,
          validator: (value) {
            if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 10) {
              return 'Please enter valid number';
            }
          },
          onSaved: (String value) {
            data.phone = value;
          },
          maxLines: 1,
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Enter your number',
              icon: const Icon(Icons.phone, color: Colors.white),
              labelStyle: new TextStyle(
                  decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.solid,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 16.0)),
        )),
    new Step(
      title: const Text('Email',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 19.0)),
      // subtitle: const Text('Subtitle'),
      isActive: false,
      state: StepState.indexed,
      // state: StepState.disabled,
      content: new TextFormField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          autocorrect: false,
          validator: (value) {
            if (value.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
              return 'Please enter valid email';
            }
          },
          onSaved: (String value) {
            data.email = value;
          },
          maxLines: 1,
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Enter your email',
              hintText: 'Enter a email address',
              icon: const Icon(Icons.email, color: Colors.white),
              labelStyle: new TextStyle(
                  decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.solid,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 16.0))),
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void showSnackBarMessage(String message,
        [MaterialColor color = Colors.red]) {
      Scaffold.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: new Text(message)));
    }

    void _submitDetails() {
      final FormState formState = _formKey.currentState;

      if (!formState.validate()) {
        showSnackBarMessage('Please enter correct data');
      } else {
        formState.save();
        // HERE
        //insertUserStep1(data.firstname, data.lastname, data.email, data.phone);

      }
    }

    return new Container(
        child: new Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: new ListView(children: <Widget>[
        new Stepper(
          steps: steps,
          type: StepperType.vertical,
          currentStep: this.currStep,
          onStepContinue: () {
            setState(() {
              if (currStep < steps.length - 1) {
                currStep = currStep + 1;
              } else {
                currStep = 0;
              }
              // else {
              // Scaffold
              //     .of(context)
              //     .showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: new Text('$currStep')));

              // if (currStep == 1) {
              //   print('First Step');
              //   print('object' + FocusScope.of(context).toStringDeep());
              // }

              // }
            });
          },
          onStepCancel: () {
            setState(() {
              if (currStep > 0) {
                currStep = currStep - 1;
              } else {
                currStep = 0;
              }
            });
          },
          onStepTapped: (step) {
            setState(() {
              currStep = step;
            });
          },
        ),
        Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: OutlineButton(
              child: Text('Tap to Continue'),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
              onPressed: _submitDetails,
            )
            //  Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new ProfileStep1()));
            ),
      ]),
    ));
  }
}
```